# when exporting environment variables with spaces in value using lastpass bash script, receiving `not a valid identifier`

Tags: bash, environment-variables, lastpass

I'm using lpass-env which uses the lpass cli to pull down a note from my vault and set them as environment variables.

The note looks similar to this:

```
VARIABLE_WITH_SPACES="abcd 1234"
VARIABLE_WITHOUT_SPACES=abcd1234
```

When the script runs the following command:

```
$(lpass show --notes mynote | awk '{ print "export", $0 }')
```

I get the following output:

```
-bash: export: `1234"': not a valid identifier
```

So it doesn't like the spaces in the value. How can I fix this?

The same thing happens if you cat a file that has spaces in some of the values:

```
$(cat file | awk '{ print "export", $0 }')
-bash: export: `1234"': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word splitting shell expansion just scans the result of command substitutions - the quotes that come after expansion of a command substitution are not special and become part of the parameters.

You could (ab-)use the `source` command and pass a process substitution:

```
. <(lpass show --notes mynote | sed 's/^/export /')
```

or be evil:

```
eval "$(lpass show --notes mynote | sed 's/^/export /')"
```

Comment: Curious why you used sed instead of awk in the OP

Comment: It seems both of these have a certain uneasiness to it?

Comment: 1) Och, I think just I am more used to `sed` then `awk`, this is just stylish. 2) Yes, I know some commands that use `eval "$(...)"`, ex. [docker-machine env](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/).